# Order direction must be "asc" or "desc" [ Laravel, Vue ]

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Trying to Sort table in laravel using Vue.js
and got this error: `Order direction must be "asc" or "desc"`.

My Controller:

```
$query = Employee::orderBy($request->column, $request->order);
$users = $query->paginate($request->per_page);
return EmployeeResource::collection($users);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please `print_r($request->all())`; and edit your question. this error means you're not getting `'asc'` or `'desc'` in `$request->order` variable.

or if get `asc` or `desc` then make it in string.

```
$order = (string) $request->order;

$query = Employee::orderBy($request->column, $order);
$users = $query->paginate($request->per_page);
```

Comment: got error
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0

Comment: print_r($request->all());

Comment: That's error is from vue js. do one thing `print_r($request->all()); exit;` and open your inspect element > go to network > select XHR > and let me know what array are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

try `return response()->json($request->all())` and look at browser console to find what data you are sending.
put the above code at the very beginning of your function.